# Get data rows from a connection table (table 3, many to many relation) to 1 column that will retrieve data from table 1 id

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Table 1 - tbl_sub (substance)

PK- ID_Sub

| ID_Sub | Name_Sub |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | aaa |
| 2 | abc |
| 3 | dd |
| 4 | a |
| 5 | e |
| 6 | yu |
| 7 | rt |

Table 2 - tbl_med (medicine)

PK- ID_med

| ID_med | Name_med | qtt_med |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | asd | 4 |
| 4 | gr | 66 |
| 5 | asd | 3 |
| 6 | tvr | 1 |
| 7 | ds | 55 |
| 8 | asd | 4 |
| 9 | re | 6 |
| 10 | gtr | 7 |
| 11 | y | 10 |
| 12 | hy | 4 |

Table 3 - tbl_connection (table 1 - table 2)

PK- ID_connection
FK- ID_med
FK- ID_sub

| ID_connection | ID_med | ID_sub |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 | 2 |
| 4 | 2 | 5 |
| 6 | 4 | 1 |
| 7 | 5 | 3 |
| 8 | 5 | 4 |
| 11 | 7 | 6 |
| 12 | 9 | 7 |
| 13 | 11 | 3 |
| 15 | 10 | 3 |
| 16 | 10 | 4 |
| 18 | 10 | 7 |
| 19 | 7 | 4 |

Already created

view_substance_stock

```
SELECT               c.ID_sub, s.Name_sub, SUM(m.Qtt_Med) AS [#_Total_Pills]
FROM                 dbo.tbl_sub AS s 
INNER JOIN           dbo.tbl_Connection AS c 
ON                   s.ID_sub = c.ID_sub 
INNER JOIN           dbo.tbl_Med AS m 
ON                   m.id_Med = c.ID_Med 
GROUP BY             c.ID_Sub, s.Name_Sub
```

| ID_sub | Name_sub | #_total_pills |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | aaa | 70 |
| 2 | abc | 4 |
| 3 | dd | 20 |
| 4 | a | 65 |
| 5 | e | 4 |
| 6 | yu | 55 |
| 7 | rt | 13 |

view_meds_stock_subs_present

```
;WITH src AS
(
SELECT          c1.[ID_Med], c1.[ID_sub], m1.[Nome_Med], m1.[Qtt_Med], 
                rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c1.[ID_Med] ORDER BY @@SPID)
FROM            [dbo].[tbl_Connection] AS c1 

LEFT JOIN       [dbo].[tbl_Med] AS m1 
ON              m1.[ID_Med] = c1.[ID_Med]
)
SELECT          *
FROM            src 
PIVOT 
(MAX([ID_sub]) FOR rn IN ([1], [2], [3], [4])) AS p;
```

| ID_med | Name_med | qtt_med | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | asd | 4 | 1 | 2 | 5 | null |
| 4 | gr | 66 | 1 | null | null | null |
| 5 | asd | 3 | 3 | 4 | null | null |
| 7 | ds | 55 | 6 | 4 | null | null |
| 9 | re | 6 | 7 | null | null | null |
| 10 | gtr | 7 | 3 | 4 | 7 | null |
| 11 | y | 10 | 3 | null | null | null |

Goal view  for view_meds_stock_subs_present -
is this possible?

| ID_med | Name_med | qtt_med | present_id_subs | present_name_subs |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | asd | 4 | 1, 2, 5 | aaa, abc, e |
| 4 | gr | 66 | 1 | aaa |
| 5 | asd | 3 | 3, 4 | dd, a |
| 6 | tvr | 1 |  |  |
| 7 | ds | 55 | 6,4 | yu, a |
| 8 | asd | 4 |  |  |
| 9 | re | 6 | 7 | rt |
| 10 | gtr | 7 | 3, 4, 7 | dd, a, rt |
| 11 | y | 10 | 3 | dd |
| 12 | hy | 4 |  |  |

Tried pivot - does not recognize AggregateFunction STRING_AGG

```
SELECT m.ID_Med, m.Name_Med, c.id_sub
FROM   [dbo].[tbl_Med] as m, [dbo].[tbl_Connection] as c
PIVOT
(  
  AggregateFunction([ID_sub])
  FOR PivotColumn IN ([ID_Connection])
) AS (Alias);
```

```
SELECT
  id_med,
  STRING_AGG(id_sub, ', ') PAS
FROM [dbo].[tbl_Connection]
GROUP BY id_med
ORDER BY id_med;
```

XML path
dynamic SQL

Comment: What sql server version are you running

Comment: log file says -> Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP2-GDR)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code gets kinda busy due to the old SQL Server version and I'm not super fond of the final output, but here's the old-school way of getting pivoted and CSV:ed data:

```sql
WITH tbl_connection AS (
    SELECT  *
    FROM    (
        VALUES  (2, 2, 1)
        ,   (3, 2, 2)
        ,   (4, 2, 5)
        ,   (6, 4, 1)
        ,   (7, 5, 3)
        ,   (8, 5, 4)
        ,   (11, 7, 6)
        ,   (12, 9, 7)
        ,   (13, 11, 3)
        ,   (15, 10, 3)
        ,   (16, 10, 4)
        ,   (18, 10, 7)
        ,   (19, 7, 4)
    ) t (ID_connection,ID_med,ID_sub)
)
, tbl_med AS (
    SELECT  *
    FROM    (
        VALUES  (2, N'asd', 4)
        ,   (4, N'gr', 66)
        ,   (5, N'asd', 3)
        ,   (6, N'tvr', 1)
        ,   (7, N'ds', 55)
        ,   (8, N'asd', 4)
        ,   (9, N're', 6)
        ,   (10, N'gtr', 7)
        ,   (11, N'y', 10)
        ,   (12, N'hy', 4)
    ) t (ID_med,Name_med,qtt_med)
)
, tbl_sub AS (
    SELECT  *
    FROM    (
    VALUES  (1, N'aaa')
    ,   (2, N'abc')
    ,   (3, N'dd')
    ,   (4, N'a')
    ,   (5, N'e')
    ,   (6, N'yu')
    ,   (7, N'rt')
) t (ID_Sub,Name_Sub)
)
, xml_foundation AS (
    SELECT  ts.id_sub
    ,   ts.name_sub
    ,   tc.ID_med
    FROM    tbl_connection tc
    INNER JOIN tbl_sub ts
        ON  ts.id_Sub = tc.ID_sub
)   
SELECT  *
,   STUFF((
    SELECT  ',' + cast(ts.id_sub AS nvarchar(max))
    FROM    xml_foundation ts
    WHERE   ts.ID_med = t.ID_med
    ORDER BY ts.id_sub
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '')
,   STUFF((
    SELECT  ',' + cast(ts.name_sub AS nvarchar(max))
    FROM    xml_foundation ts
    WHERE   ts.ID_med = t.ID_med
    ORDER BY ts.id_sub
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '')
FROM    tbl_med t
```

You have to use FOR XML trick to get the comma-separated values. Important is to sort them properly, I use `ORDER BY ts.id_sub` instead of `ORDER BY @@SPID` because the second is non-deterministic.

`STUFF((SELECT... FOR XML...).value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '')` is the plumbing needed, it converts the XML node into it's text representation, and removes the first ','.

The output becomes:

| ID_med | Name_med | qtt_med | (column 4) | (column 5) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | asd | 4 | 1,2,5 | aaa,abc,e |
| 4 | gr | 66 | 1 | aaa |
| 5 | asd | 3 | 3,4 | dd,a |
| 6 | tvr | 1 | NULL | NULL |
| 7 | ds | 55 | 4,6 | a,yu |
| 8 | asd | 4 | NULL | NULL |
| 9 | re | 6 | 7 | rt |
| 10 | gtr | 7 | 3,4,7 | dd,a,rt |
| 11 | y | 10 | 3 | dd |
| 12 | hy | 4 | NULL | NULL |

Comment: this is perfect @siggemannen, works like a charm 
added column names after the xml path values 
thanks for your major help, all the best to you :)